# Kernel live-patching in kernel 4?

Tags: security, 15.10

According to [Linux 4 release documentation](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.0), live-patching of kernel code is now possible in Linux 4.

Does Ubuntu 15.10 Wily support these live in-RAM patches without rebooting? Do I need to do anything to get this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Correct, 15.10 contained the plumbing in the kernel, however generating the patches was left as a tricky bit.

But, good news, This is now available as a service from Canonical in Ubuntu 16.04:

- http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html
- https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch

There is a free tier as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this feature is not supported in 15.10.

In the [Linux 4 release documentation](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.0), it states that "livepatch is not feature complete". Ubuntu 15.10 is at kernel 4.2 now, but I don't see any items about livepatch in the [Linux 4.1 release documentation](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.1) or the merge window notes for 4.2 or 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question at SCALE. Live kernel patching isn't going to be here in 16.04, probably not in 16.10 but maybe in 17.04 according to what the presenters said.